# Algorithm for finding contradictions in a directed graph that represents implications

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network

I need an algorithm that does this:

> For a directed graph where nodes represent boolean values and edges represent implication (implies TRUE and implies FALSE):
>         If (arc exists between any node $A$ and any node $B$ such that ($A\to B$ AND $A\to !B$) OR ($!A\to B$ AND $!A\to !B$) )
>               then return FALSE, else return TRUE

Does such an algorithm already exist?

Comment: If it doesn't why don't you try your hands on creating one?

Comment: Of course there is one, just walk through all arcs.

Comment: @MonK I would if it didn't exist.

Comment: Related: [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), [DPLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm), [forward chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_chaining), [backward chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_chaining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such general terms, the only algorithm is exhaustion. Walk through all possible paths of your graph and check for consistency. It is possible that there is a much better way depending on your assumptions about the graph.